# Deleting rows with specific timekey in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

[image]I have a table with entries of specific time key .Every month table should update with  results from previous three months . Records pervious to that should be deleted .the scrip automatically run every month .Is there a way to achieve this in hive ?

Comment: What is the time key here? Is it possible to derive date values from time key?

Comment: timekey is the date in yymmdd format . Yes  date value can be derived from it

Comment: timekey looks like yyyyMM, partition your table by yyyyMM, you will be able to drop or filter partitions without doing full scan

Comment: is it external table?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it via query.

```
insert overwrite table <tablename>
select 
col1,
col2,
....
from tablename where timekey >(select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(add_months(current_date(),-3), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyMM'));
```

above query will read the table data and insert only last 3 months records

Answer (score 0):

As far as delete updates are concern Hive will not support such operations, but with new hive version transactions are supported. But you need to create transaction hive table for that.

Below is syntax you can have while creating this transaction table,

```
CREATE TABLE hello_acid (key int, value int)
PARTITIONED BY (load_date date)
CLUSTERED BY(key) INTO 3 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

You can refer below link for more details,
https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/using-hive-acid-transactions-to-insert-update-and-delete-data/

Hope this will help.

Comment: Does this solution useful ?